# How do I decrypt encrypted files from Windows XP

Tags: windows, encryption

I have the original Windows XP hard drive in an external HDD enclosure.
How do I extract the decryption key from it? It was used as a hard drive for Windows XP. I need to decrypt photos.

Comment: What type of encryption was used? If Windows XP was installed as Pro version then the encryption could be the Windows integrated EFS which you can trigger in the context menu of files/folders. Was it that encryption?

Comment: If you could do that it would render encryption useless.

Comment: @Robert Windows xp pro , i have the original hard drive in an hdd enclosure how do i decrypt files

Comment: The encryption key is in the user profile that belongs to the Windows XP installation. And you need the password of the Windows XP user account as the key is encrypted by this password. If you miss the profile or the password and don't have exported the EFS key the data is gone.

Comment: @Robert I know the password of the user account used on that laptop how do i get the key

Comment: I never tried it myself as I always make a backup but this guide looks promising. The whole process is a bit complex but necessary if you don't want to pay a lot of money for a tool that can do this on it's own https://tinyapps.org/docs/decrypt-efs-without-cert-backup.html

Comment: @Robert I understand the guide but not step 3. Do I have to manually search all of them or is there a way to automate it, I hope I don't have to search them manually as there are 1020 items in the folder

Comment: If I understand the steps correctly this is for extracting the certificate and it's private key. There is usually only one cert+key per user account.

Comment: @Robert it says it is for cracking efs, i just dont understand step 3

Comment: Step 3 is executed within Mimikatz.

Comment: @Robert how do i do step 3,can you explain im noob in computer

Comment: Sorry I can't help you on that I never did this. Just download mimikatz and make yourself familiar with it. The necessary command are on this linked web page.

Comment: @Robert I do not know computers very well (couldn't figure out Mimikatz) but I used Elcomsoft EFS Data Recovery (Cracked version) and it worked perfectly!